# What is the default font in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I changed my default styles in Google Docs, but would like to know what Google Docs originally "ships" with, without tweaking my default styles.

What is the original font and size that comes with Google Docs?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It's mostly Arial in different sizes, 5 styles have different colors, and the last one is in Italics.

Other default settings:

- Header & footers:

  - Margins:

    - Header(inches from top): 0.5
    - Footer (inches from bottom): 0.5
- Page setup:

  - Margins (inches): 1 for all (Top, Bottom, Left, Right)